# getAnnotationsByType (Java 8) desugaring not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use Java 8 features through desugaring in SDK < 24.
getAnnotationByType should be supported according to https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support?hl=el but I encounter `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotationsByType`

Is desugaring not working for this use case? According to google documentation, "Repeating Annotations" are supported.

Do note that all my other desugaring works fine, it isn't an issue with me not specifying desugaring options in my build.gradle incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desugaring of `java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotationsByType` is only supported on API 26+.